# Convert SQL Server 2008 table column as XML and aggregate xpath values

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I've got a table with xml stored in `NVARCHAR`. It's just like that.

The xml looks like

```
<Container>
  <Data>
    <SomeNode>val1</SomeNode>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <SomeNode>val2</SomeNode>
  </Data>
</Container>
```

basically I need a to query all val1...valX from all the xml strings in table.

So far I've managed to come up with

```
SELECT CAST(XmlColumn AS XML).query('//SomeNode') FROM ThatTableWithXmlInStrings
```

which gives me list of lists of nodes. And here I'm lost: how do I flatten that into single values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')
from ThatTableWithXmlInStrings
  cross apply (select cast(XmlColumn as xml)) T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('/Container/Data/SomeNode') as T2(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods:

1. add text() function to the xquery
2. use nodes method [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)

Comment: you mean query('//SomeNode/text()') ?
that just glues val0val1, val2, val3val4 which is not what i need

Comment: Sorry, I had something else in mind, try the second method that one is what you need